# Arduino Software serial not showing the received data

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, datalogging

I get the data from a sensor which is in RS485. I am using RS485-RS232 Converter. Then its given to uart usb converter and I get the data in TTL. I am able to receive the data in uart (hyperterminal). I have connected the TX, RX, GND pins to 10, 11, GND pins of Arduino UNO.
I want to communicate it with Arduino UNO through SoftSerial and here is the code

```C++
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define rxPin 10
#define txPin 11

SoftwareSerial mySerial =  SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {   
    pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop()
{  
    while (mySerial.available() > 0) {
        Serial.println("Data is available");
        Serial.println(mySerial.read());
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to see the data on serial monitor.

Comment: `After converting it to RS232, its given to uart converter where i get data in TTL` - please edit your post to show your wiring.

Comment: Also please show what these mysterious converters are that you have used. Model numbers, connector types, etc.

Comment: The phrase *"given to uart usb converter"* immediately rings alarm bells to me - is this something that you plug into a USB port, and you are now trying to connect it to a TTL UART input?

Comment: Did you reverse tx and rx pins?

Comment: Majenko...Its an nT RS422 to RS232 converter.After that its connected to UART USB   converter which has max3233. I'm getting data properly at hyper terminal. Then  i have connected RX TX pins of it  to TX RX of microcontroller. But not able get the output.

Comment: Yes i have reversed the RX TX pins @Visual Micro

Comment: Confirm each step. Do you have data when going directly from 485 to 232 into Hyperterminal?  Do you have communication between Arduino and Hyperterminal without the extra software serial stuff? If you do then it's probably something to do with how its pulling data from your software serial and sending it to the Serial.println(). Try using mySerial.readline() or change the Serial.println(mySerial.read()) to Serial.print(mySerial.read()).

Comment: Remove setting the pinMode(). Note required for SoftwareSerial

Comment: Yes i have data from 485 to 232 to Hyperterminal and o checked in hyperterminal also. Communication between Arduino and Hyperterminal is not happening. Only if i press RESET button once, i am able to get one data. If i press RESET many times then data is displayed on serial monitor. And data is displayed properly on Serial Monitor if i remove the microcontroller (ATMEGA328). So i thought of using Software Serial. @ChefFlambe

Comment: Okay @VisualMicro

Comment: Still not getting output. Don't know what is wrong

Comment: Is your end goal to have the Arduino act only as a bridge to a PC for sensor data?

Comment: No it not like that. I want to manipulate the data coming from sensor using Arduino and then store it onto SD Card. Its kind of a datalogger  @Chef Flambe

Comment: **Voting to close as this question was abandoned in unanswerable form over a year ago.**

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to yours recently.

The thing that got me was that the RS232 from the Arduino is reverse. This is because it would usually go through a RS232 IC that produces +12 and -12 signals.

A sensor or RS232 backpack on a LCD cannot deal with the reverse signals.

The SoftwareSerial library has an undocumented feature that will reverse the RS232 output for you.

When you configure your interface do the following:

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2, true);
```

The true option instructs the library to reverse the RS232 signals.
Hope this helps you out since this post was a long time ago.

Comment: While occasionally useful, this overlooks the dangerous issue that even apart from the inversion, the Arduino cannot safely handle RS232 levels.  Pretty much every level shifter intended for RS232 is an *inverting* level shifter - so this issue basically only comes up with homegrown minimalist implementations, and would not be expected to occur with the MAX3233 the poster says they are using.